# How to get data from Azure Easy Tables made for an android app in website?

Tags: javascript, azure

I created a simple backend for my android app using Azure easy tables and I was wondering how (and if) I can perform CRUD operations from a simple, non-asp.net website I'm making. I'm hoping to be only using js for this but if that is not possible, then I'll be open for other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you can use to perform CRUD with Javascript after you set up easy tables on Azure.

1. Make AJAX requests to table endpoints. All HTTP interfaces that the SDK exposes to you can be found in [the article](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-13-the-http-table-interface/).
2. Use the [JavaScript client library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client) to work with tables. For more information, see [How to Use the JavaScript client library for Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library#table-reference).